# Is there any way to control my server without using SSH

Tags: ssh

I want to turn my raspberry pi into a personal server than I can access from anywhere but from what I've learnt SSH requires port forwarding to access from another network but my internet provider (Vodafone) does not allow port 22 forwarding . Is there anyway to achieve the same thing that SSH does? Maybe some sort of TCP reverse shell is viable. I'm new to all of this.

Comment: I think this question is better suited at Superuser.com, as it's not about IT in a business environment.

Comment: Depending on your router, you could map a different external port to port 22 on your device.  Google the name of your router and the term "port forwarding" for router specific instructions.  Note that exposing anything publicly is a security risk; so be careful what you expose / ensure things are secured appropriately before opening them up to the internet.

Comment: As for alternatives, there's things like XRDP (https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-xrdp-on-raspberry-pi/); which give a way to remote onto your device via the RDP port (3389 by default).  However, likely those would also use ports that are blocked by default / would require the same port forwarding as above.

Comment: You can also move (or duplicate) ssh to another port directly in its configuration.

Comment: Or you can use a web terminal; i.e. host a website with a login page on your device, and have that proxy commands to its hosts terminal.  There's a thread about that here: https://www.reddit.com/r/raspberry_pi/comments/1thdrp/tutorial_web_based_ssh_terminal_for_the_raspberry/ - I've no experience with these solutions, so can't offer any insights other than knowing such things exist and avoid the port forwarding issue.

Answer (score 1):

1. To control Raspberry Pi without using SSH

- Try XRDP
- Or consider telnet (not recommended)

2. To connect SSH from internet when port 22 is blocked

- Edit port setting in sshd_config
- Or set up VPN (OpenVPN, or WireGuard, etc.)